# Hardware Configuration required to run Multi Node Hadoop on a Laptop

Tags: laptop, processor, memory

I am looking for a laptop which can withstand

1. Hadoop multi node installation
2. Sqoop queries.
3. Db's like Oracle or MySQL
4. Eclipse IDE for JAVA.
5. Documentation work(MSWord,MSExcel,MSPowerpoint).
6. VMWare

All these things will be running mostly at same time.
I have 2 options:-

1. i5 with 8GB RAM.
2. i7 with 8GB RAM.

Which has sufficient power and memory for these tasks?

Budget: 45k INR (~670 USD)

Comment: If you're running all this software at one time, you'll need a very powerful CPU (mostly for VMWare and Eclipse) and equally powerful RAM to go with it. That means, in my opinion, at _least_ and i7 and at _least_ 16GB memory. Other than that, what physical requirements do you have? A certain number of USB ports, a specific video port, screen size, etc?

Comment: Why does this have to be done on a laptop?

Comment: @Adam Thanks a lot.Right now my main concern is learning Hadoop and its component.In that regards,it is all i need,i think.If you have some other criteria in your mind for running all these,please,do specify.

Comment: @AdamWykes The nature of my job makes me travel,so i am going for a laptop.

Comment: @Adam you coolmment should become the answer.

Comment: @AdamWykes if that was an answer, I'd delete it for lack of a recommendation.

Comment: I'm sure you would. However, in this case the structure of the question makes it clear that answering "i7" conclstitutes a sufficient answer. Adam then goes on to provide detail as to why, and discusses some other requirements as well. The author of the question seems to back my interpretation. Moreover, I never said he shouldnt flesh it out a little more when it becomes an answer (he should, to avoid mods that don't always have time to read what they should before acting).